# Need to select best Azure service to access on-premises sql database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azureservicebus

I have a business scenario where web site and SQL database will be on cloud and after some operations want to save the cloud SQL data to the SQL database which is on-premises and not exposed to the internet.

What would be the best architecture for this scenario?

Need suggestions.

Comment: There are several ways to solve this. There's no "best" architecture for syncing your cloud database with on-premises database. And you've shared nothing about the app specifics (e.g. what if you're syncing 1TB per hour?) Anyway... this is going to end up getting you opinions, and that's not a good fit for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the website does not use local resources you can always go for azure websites. Choose the tier based on the requirement.

As far as the database is concerned you choose azure sql database. ( tier based on requirement-size and performance) . You can set up azure sql sync (in preview) to sync between sql azure and local sql server. Or you can take a back up of sql azure db - bacpac. and then restore it local sql server using sql management studio.

Comment: Hi. thanks for the quick answer. But, my cloud sql and on-premise sql database will have different structure. I need to send some necessary information to on-premise database. which is confirmed by the user.

Comment: Cool. If you are happy with the answer please mark it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can either setup a VNET to connect your Website to your on-premises SQL Server or you can configure Azure Hybrid Connect. (see this [link](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/30/using-vnet-or-hybrid-conn-with-websites/))

Comment: Azure provides you to create your own VNET. The Azure will then be able to access the SQL from your intranet

Comment: isn't that what i've just stated above?

Comment: Can service bus and relay help me in my problem statement? I need the local resources for my web site to store the uploaded files. and then I will sync it to on-premise server. So, if I write azure service bus which will do sql data and uploaded file sync for me.